# How to solve the "error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt" ij Angular 7 using Let's Encrypt certificates?

Tags: angular, encryption, certificate

I have an Angular 7 application which should work with a Let's Encrypt certificate.

I am running the application using the configuration below:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check  --ssl true  --ssl-cert ./ssl/certificate.crt --ssl-key ./ssl/certificate.key
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my problem by removing the private key from encrypted key certificate.

openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key

Lifted from here - [Some helpful link](https://www.xolphin.com/support/Certificate_conversions/Convert_pfx_file_to_pem_file)

Comment: did you get the same error from above? Im assuming your certificate does not have private key.